# GetElementsByTagName('a') stopped working after server restart

Tags: html, powershell

I have this in my script:

```
$link = $ie.Document.GetElementsByTagName('a') |
        Where-Object {$_.InnerText -eq'xxxxxx'} |
        select -First 1
```

It was working all fine, and suddenly it stopped working; it stopped working after sever restart and probably something got updated, this script is still working on my machine.

The server has PowerShell v5.0; while on my local machine it's v5.1.

Could that be the problem?

Comment: Please edit the question and add more details describing what, exactly, `stopped working` means. No results? Wrong results? Error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pretty much always run into issues when using the IE com object.

try using

```
$IE.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByTagName()
```

instead and see if that fixes your issue, the `IHTMLDocument2/3` Methods are generally more reliable on the later versions of powershell.

Comment: $ie.document.body.getElementsByTagName worked with me, but I am still concerned about this, i ll try yours.

Comment: @Sam I find the `.body` to be much slower, i'd compare the two using `Measure-Command` if you're really worried about the 'best' one, otherwise flip a coin :)

Comment: You could always do both so if one fails you can try the other as a backup.